# IE ERROR 'object doesn't support this property or method when is use window.dialogargument()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, exception, notsupportedexception

I am getting error like *"Object doesn't support this property or method"* in IE only, when I use `window.dialogArguments` method. It's working fine in the remaining browsers (Mozilla, Chrome).

Sample code:

```
if(window.navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){     
   window.dialogArguments.setCopyFromValues(segmentCode,segmentName,status);        
   window.close();
}
```

I am getting error `window.dialogArgument` place.

Comment: What's with the double `{{` and `}}`?

Comment: @justcurious: Never fix the OP's code in edits.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Got it. OP's code originally contained an unwanted '}'. That's why removed it. Btw, what you have edited now is not OP's original code. See the revision.

Comment: I see... Your edit introduced that mistake...

Comment: For the record,  my edit didn't introduce any mistake in the code. Anyone looking correctly at the revision can understand it clearly. Having said that, I don't want to go into argument mode and spam this question with unwanted comments. Your point is not to edit OP's code and I clearly get it and will consider it gng frwd. Thanks!